# Apache Jack Rabbit JCA 2.6.0.rar Installation on Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, jcr, jackrabbit

I am trying to install Resource Adapter of JCA (Jack Rabbit) version 2.6.0 on Websphere (v9) but i get error that JCAManagedConnectionFactory can't be found. I have also tried other versions of JCA but still of no help. 
I have downloaded the the rar from following location
http://archive.apache.org/dist/jackrabbit/2.6.0/jackrabbit-jca-2.6.0.rar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[09/06/18 16:05:05:109 CDT] 0000009c J2CAppUtils   E   ADMN0051E: The service failed to introspect the class:org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory. The exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jcr.RepositoryException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:302)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1313)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1347)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1208)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:437)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:184)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.J2CAppUtils.getDefinedProperties(J2CAppUtils.java:406)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.InstallRAHelper.loadBeanPropertyWithType(InstallRAHelper.java:253)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.InstallRAHelper.loadBeanProperty(InstallRAHelper.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.InstallRAHelper.configureCDTmp(InstallRAHelper.java:985)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.InstallRAHelper.setOutboundRA(InstallRAHelper.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminOperationsMBean.createJ2CPost10ResourceAdapter(AdminOperationsMBean.java:1429)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminOperationsMBean.createJ2CPost10ResourceAdapter(AdminOperationsMBean.java:1234)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminOperationsMBean._getResourceAdapterFromRAR(AdminOperationsMBean.java:1086)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminOperationsMBean.getResourceAdapterFromRAR(AdminOperationsMBean.java:967)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.tasks.InstallRARTask.invoke(InstallRARTask.java:511)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.tasks.InstallRARTask.installResourceAdapter(InstallRARTask.java:224)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.jca.J2CCommandProvider.installResourceAdapter(J2CCommandProvider.java:1121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.provider.SimpleCommandProvider.executeReal(SimpleCommandProvider.java:156)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.provider.SimpleCommandProvider.execute(SimpleCommandProvider.java:142)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.provider.SimpleAdminCommand.execute(SimpleAdminCommand.java:57)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database.j2c.J2CResourceAdapterInstallDetailAction.execute(J2CResourceAdapterInstallDetailAction.java:210)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:518)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:339)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jcr.RepositoryException
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.util.ArchiveFileDynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ArchiveFileDynamicClassLoader.java:630)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
    ... 82 more
```

WebSphere error Image:

[image: WebSphere error Image]

Answer (score 0):

The environment seems to be missing the jcr library in the classpath. Try after adding the jcr-2.0 jar to the rar file. Should work.